# implement the next function of interable to iterate over a 2D array in kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I have a custom class that is `array<array<K>>`. I want to iterate over it with `forEach`, you know, the way we do with arrays in kotlin. I implement the `iterable<k>` and the `hasNext` function is easy. Problem is, the `next` function is hard because now I have columns and the columns are of different sizes.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to write next(). Some hints in the right direction is fine.

Comment: Please show how you have implemented the "easy" parts then.

Comment: Ok. I'll post my code. I know it pales in comparison to dev boris, but I hope it might help beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my own question. In fact, I am doing this as a self-set exercise to a tutorial about coding a hashmap.

```
  override fun iterator(): Iterator<K> {
  return object : Iterator<K> {
   var stopLoopNumber = 0
   var rowEntry = 0
   var columnEntry = 0

   override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
    return stopLoopNumber < getAllEntries()
   }

   override fun next(): K {
    //check if a row has more than one entry. if so, increment the column to output all entries in the column.
    //at the same time increment the stopLoopNumber each time an entry is output.
    return if (columnEntry < entries[rowEntry].size) {
     stopLoopNumber++
     entries[rowEntry][columnEntry++].key
    } else {
     // the column is exhausted, so reset it to 0, ready for the next row.
     columnEntry = 0
     stopLoopNumber++
     //move to the next row and after outputting the entry, increment the column. This is vital because we must
     //increment the column after an entry is output.
     entries[++rowEntry][columnEntry++].key
    }
   }
  }
 }
```